# "Целям, которые" - согласование

Tags: согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать в данном случае?

Я понял, что это тот коллектив, в котором я бы хотел творить, он стремится к тем целям, которые я бы хотел достичь.

Или:

Я понял, что это тот коллектив, в котором я бы хотел творить, он стремится к тем целям, которых я бы хотел достичь.

Я склоняюсь ко второму варианту, но объяснить не могу...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я понял, что это тот коллектив, в котором я бы хотел творить, он стремится к тем целям, которых (Р.п.) я бы хотел достичь.

**Глагол "достичь" (чего?) управляет  Р.п. , поэтому достичь целей.**

Союзное слово КОТОРЫХ в придаточном заменяет существительное "цели", но ставится в том падеже, которого требует управляющий глагол.

ДОСТИЧЬ, 3. чего. Дойти до какого-л. уровня, предела в своём развитии, проявлении, в каких-л. изменениях. Д. высшей ступени развития.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот я и чувствовала, что так будет грамотнее, а объяснить не могла.. По-другому как-то просто не по-русски получается...